# ajax loading not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

The ajaxstart function is not triggering in chrome but it works fine in firefox,

here is the js

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () { 
        $("#waiting").css("display", "block"); 
    }); 

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () { 
        $("#waiting").css("display", "none"); 
    });
});
```

And the HTML

```
 <div id="waiting" style="display:none;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;padding:2px;background: rgba(129, 129, 129, 0.54) url('images/1.gif') no-repeat center center;z-index: 999;"></div>
```

Comment: Try some alternate `$("#waiting").show()` and `$("#waiting").hide()`

Comment: And the actual Ajax call?

Comment: The code that you provided is working fine. http://jsbin.com/juyofupanu/1/

Comment: And do you trigger any ajax on your page? And the other, it is seems a little bit strange to me: `top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;` What if you do not hide your div, when page loaded, do you see the layer?

Comment: Tried , but still not working in chrome :(

Comment: @lolka_bolka no layer is in chrome but it is fine in firefox , what is the issue with the chrome

Comment: lets try remove the right and bottom parameters, and scroll to the most top of your screen. It should be in top-left corner.

Comment: @MateuszNowak it is not working for me

Comment: and temporary add a width, and height to it, and a red border around. After this, you can check your script.

Comment: @lolka_bolka will try it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p1kbja5s/

Comment: @lolka_bolka tried , but zero change :(
It is showing when i tried in debugger mode, :-p

Comment: See @MateuszNowak solution in comments. Do you get any error message in console? Are you loading the jQuery? Can you present us a live example?

Comment: It might be as well chrome z-index bug. Google that.

Comment: Take Ajax out of the picture. Just call the line `$("#waiting").css("display", "block");` in the console. Does the layer show up?

Comment: @epascarello yeh, the layer shows. It is showing when i tried in debugger mode, :-p

Comment: Hi all
I figured out the issue, **Make all ajax call asynchronous true**
Thanks all

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the issue, here i am sharing with all

---

> Make all ajax call asynchronous true.

---

Now it will be fine in all browsers.
Thanks all

Answer (score -4):

try to replace your ajax function with

```
jQuery("#waiting").show() and jQuery("#waiting").hide()
```